# Simple regex for matching up to an optional character?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'm sure this is a simple question for someone at ease with regular expressions:

I need to match everything up until the character #

I don't want the string following the # character, just the stuff before it, and the character itself should not be matched. This is the most important part, and what I'm mainly asking. As a second question, I would also like to know how to match the rest, after the # character. But not in the same expression, because I will need that in another context.

Here's an example string:

topics/install.xml#id_install

I want only topics/install.xml. And for the second question (separate expression) I want id_install

Comment: please add example strings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First expression:

```
^([^#]*)
```

Second expression:

```
#(.*)$
```

Comment: Ok, this worked if I added an asterisk in the first expression, like so: ^([^#]*)

Comment: BTW: What does this sign do, at the beginning: ^ ? Thank you!

Comment: @Anders: Updated the expressions. The caret `^` matches from the beginning of the string the `$` matches from the ending of the string.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but the second expression still includes the # character in the match when I try it. Still, the first expression is the only one that I got to work here, so I'll take this as the answer. If you could check why the second includes the # character, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @Anders: Are you accessing the group `$1` or the whole matched string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use C#, but i will assume that it uses pcre... if so,

```
"([^#]*)#.*"
```

with a call to 'match'. A call to 'search' does not need the trailing ".*"

The parens define the 'keep group'; the  [^#] means any character that is not a '#'

You probably tried something like

```
"(.*)#.*"
```

and found that it fails when multiple '#' signs are present (keeping the leading '#'s)?
That is because  ".*" is greedy, and will match as much as it can.

Your matcher should have a method that looks something like 'group(...)'. Most matchers
return the entire matched sequence as group(0), the first paren-matched group as group(1),
and so forth.

PCRE is so important i strongly encourage you to search for it on google, learn it, and always have it in your programming toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\#]
```

If your string contains any other special characters you need to add them into the first square bracket escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Use look ahead and look behind:

- To get all characters up to, but not including the pound (#): `.*?(?=\#)`
- To get all characters following, but not including the pound (#): `(?<=\#).*`

If you don't mind using groups, you can do it all in one shot:

- `(.*?)\#(.*)`  Your answers will be in group(1) and group(2).  Notice the non-greedy construct, `*?`, which will attempt to match as little as possible instead of as much as possible.
- If you want to allow for missing # section, use `([^\#]*)(?:\#(.*))?`.  It uses a non-collecting group to test the second half, and if it finds it, returns everything after the pound.

Honestly though, for you situation, it is probably easier to use the `Split` method provided in `String`.

[More on lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: `.*(?=#)` will match up until the last `#`, not the first. Also, it might be better to escape the pound sign's as some engines consider it a comment (# ... eol), if the expanded flag is set.

Comment: You are right.  Updated answer to use non-greedy and escaped the #

Answer (score 0):

first:
`/[^\#]*(?=\#)/`  **edit**: is faster than `/.*?(?=\#)/`

second:
`/(?<=\#).*/`

Answer (score 0):

For something like this in C# I would usually skip the regular expressions stuff altogether and do something like:

```
string[] split = exampleString.Split('#');
string firstString = split[0];
string secondString = split[1];
```